# Android Listview does not refresh/redraw

Tags: android, listview

Problem - I have list of in app purchases loaded from app store in a Listview. 
When user purchases (taps on a button in listview) the item is purchased and the button should be now hidden and the list item purchased should show an image of tick.

What I have tried -

1. Refresh the listview after item is purchased by calling `notifyDataSetChanged`
2. Set the visibility of the button and image using `View.GONE` and `View.VISIBLE`

None of the above seems to work.
I am using [this](https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3) in app billing library

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Product> {

    private ArrayList<Product> iapProducts= new ArrayList<>();
    private final LayoutInflater inflater;
    private final Activity activity;

    public ArrayList<Product> getIapProducts() {
        return iapProducts;
    }

    public void setIapProducts(ArrayList<Product> iapProducts) {
        this.iapProducts = iapProducts;
    }

    public ListViewAdapter(final Activity context) {
        super(context, 0);
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.activity = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.iapProducts.size();
    }

    public String getItem(String position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds(){
        return true;
    }

    public void addAll(ArrayList<Product> iapProducts){
        this.iapProducts.addAll(iapProducts);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    public static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView name;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public Button purchaseButton;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.names_filter_row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.name = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.languageName);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imgTick);
            holder.purchaseButton = (Button) vi.findViewById(R.id.iapProductPurchaseBtn);
            vi.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
        }
        final Product product = iapProducts.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(product.getTitle());


        holder.purchaseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onItemPurchased(v);
            }
        });

        holder.iapProductId.setText(product.getProductId());
        holder.purchaseButton.setText(product.getPriceText());
        holder.imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if(product.isPurchased()){
            holder.purchaseButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }else{
            holder.purchaseButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        return vi;
    }





    private void onItemPurchased(View v){
        final RelativeLayout parentLayout = (RelativeLayout)v.getParent();
        final TextView productId = (TextView)parentLayout.findViewById(R.id.iapProductId);
        final ImageView languageCheck = (ImageView)parentLayout.findViewById(R.id.imgTick);
        PurchaseActivity purchaseActivity = (PurchaseActivity) this.activity;
        purchaseActivity.purchaseItem(productId.getText().toString(), v);
    }
}


public class PurchaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BillingProcessor.IBillingHandler {

    private BillingProcessor bp;
    boolean isOneTimePurchaseSupported;
    private ArrayList<Product> productsToPurchase = new ArrayList<>();
    private final static String TAG = PurchaseActivity.class.getName();


    private ListViewAdapter adapter;
    private ImageView imageTick;
    private Button buttonPurchase;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_purchase);

        bp = BillingProcessor.newBillingProcessor(this, "billingKey", this); // doesn't bind
        bp.initialize(); // binds
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this);
        nameFilterListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (!bp.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBillingInitialized() {
        isOneTimePurchaseSupported = bp.isOneTimePurchaseSupported();
        if(isOneTimePurchaseSupported){
          loadIAPData(false);
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this,"Billing not supported",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private void loadIAPData(boolean showProgressDialog){

        bp.loadOwnedPurchasesFromGoogle();
        final List<SkuDetails> productDetails = bp.getPurchaseListingDetails(productList);
        if(productDetails!= null && !productDetails.isEmpty()){

                //fetch products and add to the list
                productsToPurchase.add(product);
            }
            //add all the products to adapter
            adapter.addAll(productsToPurchase);
        } 
    }

    public void purchaseItem(@NonNull  final String productId, final View imageTick, final View button){
        this.imageTick = (ImageView) imageTick;
        this.buttonPurchase = (Button) button;
        bp.purchase(this,productId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProductPurchased(String productId, TransactionDetails details) {
        //hide button show image
        this.imageTick.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        this.buttonPurchase.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        adapter.setIapProducts(new ArrayList<>(productsToPurchase));
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

}
```

Comment: After a user purchases something, is that Product within productsToPurchase updated? The adapter looks okie so maybe the list you're using isn't being updated after a purchase. I'm assuming you need to flip the isPurchased flag of the Product in onProductPurchased() using the provided productId

Comment: That did the trick, thanks. happy to accept your answer if you post one :)

Comment: good to hear! I've posted as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(Moved comment into a post)**

After a user purchases something, is that Product within productsToPurchase updated? The adapter looks okie so maybe the list you're using isn't being updated after a purchase.

I'm assuming you need to flip the isPurchased flag of the Product in onProductPurchased() using the provided productId.